Safari iOS linear-gradient with color-mix issues with "Full Page" screenshot issues
I have a web site that uses CSS linear-gradient with color-mix for a background of a division. It shows up just fine in Safari on iOS and iPadOS 17.4.1. When do a screenshot, and select "Full Page", the background-image becomes all black and the text in the division is unreadable.
This is what I am doing.


div.ugly
{
    background-image : linear-gradient(to right, yellow, color-mix(in srgb, red, blue));
    height           : 100px;
}
<div class="ugly">Something ugly</div>



Any ideas how to get the background not turn black?
I've tried using a print media query, but the "Full Page" screenshot does not use that.
It looks like it might be a bug in iOS/iPadOS.
Thanks,
Mike
